# How to add a single index to the createdAt field in a Strapi collection (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection in which I need to make queries filtering by date, so I’d like to add an index to the **createdAt** field (this field was created automatically when I created the collection in Strapi Content-types builder).

I already added some indexes for other fields that are working fine in */models/{name}.settings.json*
according to:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/best-approaching-for-adding-custom-indexes/888/7

but there is no createdAt attribute in the /models/{name}.settings.json file

I've tried adding the index manually in mongo but as in the original question from the [Strapi forum post](https://forum.strapi.io/t/best-approaching-for-adding-custom-indexes/888) Strapi drops it when reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can define createdAt field in your schema and then index it. Defining like

```
const yourSchema = mongoose.Schema({
createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now()
}
})

yourSchema.index({
createdAt: 1
})
```

Comment: Hi r_dmr, thank you for your time. The thing is that I don't know how or where to add that code in strapi. Regards

Comment: You have to add it in your database model file